# Periodic fetch from API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make my app fetch data from API every 5 seconds without refreshing the page every time.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Hi, with a timer ?

Comment: @mollusk , I don't know exactly , but as I mentioned ,every 5 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried Timer.periodic?

Comment: Can you provide how ? I tried but I keep getting errors .

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple timer that runs every a HTTP lookup every 5 seconds.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import "dart:async";

void main() {
  
  var timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (_) async {
    var album = await fetchAlbum();
    print(album.body);
    //Update page with data here
  });
}
Future<http.Response> fetchAlbum() {
  return http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));
}
```

I have included a basic HTTP lookup from here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
Without knowing more about your app I can't give anymore information.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is facing this error , I fixed it like this.

```
    Timer? t;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    t = new Timer.periodic(timeDelay, (t) => fetchDocuments());
  }
    @override
  void dispose() {
    t?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```